# First make it so the bigger value is in a

Tags: java

```
if (b > a) {
int temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp; }
```

why do I need to save a in b this way to make sure the bigger value is in a, instead of simply

```
if(b>a){ 
a=b; }
```

It doesn't work this way but I don't understand why exactly. Don't u write the same expression 3 times ?

Comment: Otherwise you'd lose the value of `a`.

Comment: The purpose is to keep both of the original values - the larger in a and the smaller in b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two pieces of code you have there are doing **two** different things. One swaps, one assigns.

Understand: **swapping** two values isn't the same as **only** assigning one value to another.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this analogy: You have two buckets. One is filled with oil and another with water. How would you exchange the contents of them? You will need a third empty bucket.

Now replace bucket with variable and you have your answer. We call it *swapping* the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(b>a){ 
a=b; }
```

if `a = 5` and `b = 10` after executing the above code both `a` and `b` will be `10`, you are assigning `b`'s value to `a`, meaning you will lose `a` forever, Imagine if you want to swap apple with orange you have to take one of them in your hand consider temp as your hand.